# Firestore Angular2 Retrieve documents based on current user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular5, angularfire2, google-cloud-filestore

I have started developing a mobile app using IONIC, ANGULAR against Google Firestore. This app will consume mostly documents based on the current user and most of my queries I will need to pass in this user. However, I am experiencing issues getting documents from firestore using the following code from my service to the page:

**user-profile.service.ts**

```
async get(){      
      // await this.afAuth.user.subscribe(currentUser => {
      //   if(currentUser){      
      //     this.userId = currentUser.uid;
      //     console.log("User Current ID: " + this.userId);

       console.log("PP:" +this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid)
          return this.userProfilesCollection.doc<UserProfile>(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(doc => {
                    const id = doc.payload.id;
                    const data = doc.payload.data();
                    return{id, ...data };
                  }
                )
            );
}
```

**landing-page.page.ts**

```
export class LandingPage implements OnInit {
  userProfile : UserProfile;

  constructor(
    private authService : AuthService,
    private loadingController : LoadingController,
    private userProfileService: UserProfileService,
    private router : Router
  ) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.loadUserProfile();
  }

  async loadUserProfile()                                                  {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Loading user profile'
    });
    await loading.present();

    this.userProfileService.get().then(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      loading.dismiss();
    })
    // this.userProfileService.get().then(
    //   res =>
    //   {
    //     loading.dismiss();
    //     res.subscribe(c=>
    //       {
    //         this.userProfile = {
    //           cellphone: c.data.cellphone,
    //           dateOfBirth: c.data.dateOfBirth,
    //           email: c.data.email,
    //           firstname: c.data.firstname,
    //           gender: c.data.gender,
    //           id: c.data.id,
    //           lastname: c.data.lastname,
    //           telephone: c.data.telephone,
    //           userId: c.data.userId,
    //           website: c.data.website
    //         };
    //       });
    //   }
    // );
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a simple example how to achieve this, and I need to use the load profile to navigate across the application as the currently logged in user will be able to manage their profile and the list items (documents) linked to them?

Comment: What exactly your requirement..!?

Comment: @pepe How to get the documents based on the CurrentUser. The method above is not working and at times the uid is null